# Postgres Streaming Replication Disk Usage Discrepancy

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

Just a quick question - apologies if its been asked before, I couldn't find it.

We are using asynchronous streaming replication with postgres and have noticed that the disk usage for the database can vary between the master and the replica, even though the databases appear to be synchronising correctly. 
At the moment the discrepancy is quite small, but it has on occasion been in the region of several GB.

At present, this is the sync status:

Master:

```
master=# SELECT pg_current_xlog_location();
 pg_current_xlog_location 
 --------------------------
 35C/F142C98
 (1 row)
```

Slave:

```
slave=# select pg_last_xlog_receive_location();
pg_last_xlog_receive_location 
-------------------------------
35C/F142C98
(1 row)
```

The disk usage is as follows. Again, I realise the discrepancy is currently quite small (~1.5GiB), but yesterday it was several GB.

Master

```
-bash-4.1$ df -m /var/lib/pgsql/
Filesystem           1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/lv_pgsql
                        401158 302898     98261  76% /var/lib/pgsql
```

Slave:

```
Filesystem           1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/lv_pgsql
                       401158 301263     99895  76% /var/lib/pgsql
```

I should clarify that the archive command is set to archive to a different partition on the master. I guess what i'm asking is:
- Is the current disk usage discrepancy normal?
- How can it be explained?
- How much of a discrepancy should there be before I get worried?

Thanks in advance for any help.

*edit* - I'm specifically interested in the discrepancy within the "data/base/*" directories which house the actual db content, as follows:

Master:

```
7   /var/lib/pgsql/master/9.3/data/base/1
7   /var/lib/pgsql/master/9.3/data/base/12891
7   /var/lib/pgsql/master/9.3/data/base/12896
57904   /var/lib/pgsql/master/9.3/data/base/16385
180 /var/lib/pgsql/master/9.3/data/base/16387
11  /var/lib/pgsql/master/9.3/data/base/16389
203588  /var/lib/pgsql/master/9.3/data/base/48448446
7   /var/lib/pgsql/master/9.3/data/base/534138292
1   /var/lib/pgsql/master/9.3/data/base/pgsql_tmp
```

Slave:

```
7   /var/lib/pgsql/slave/9.3/data/base/1
7   /var/lib/pgsql/slave/9.3/data/base/12891
7   /var/lib/pgsql/slave/9.3/data/base/12896
57634   /var/lib/pgsql/slave/9.3/data/base/16385
180 /var/lib/pgsql/slave/9.3/data/base/16387
10  /var/lib/pgsql/slave/9.3/data/base/16389
202945  /var/lib/pgsql/slave/9.3/data/base/48448446
7   /var/lib/pgsql/slave/9.3/data/base/534138292
1   /var/lib/pgsql/slave/9.3/data/base/pgsql_tmp
```

Comment: Postgres' data directory contains many things, including logging, that will be different between master and standby.  Comparing the number of blocks they use makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks Andromar, have added further info now to exclude logging etc